# billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).getPurchasesList() returning null

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I'm making an app for android with billing services. I've already added the "shop" method, so the user can subscript. My app has only one subscriptionfor sale. The problem is that when the user open the app I can't get if he has subscript or not. Until now, I've come to this code, even when the user is subscript`purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()` returns `null`:

```
premium = false

try{
            Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

        for (Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {

            acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();

            acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    premium = true;
                }
            };

            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }}
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

handlePurchase method:

```
 void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .build();
                billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            }
            else SplashScreenActivity.premium = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm looking forward to check if the user is subscribed so, I can set `premium = true`. Until now, I'm using an ugly solution that is buy the product again and check if it returns ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED. Still looking for a better solution.

**NOTE**: I'm getting this result on alpha test.

**NOTE 2**: [This link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#pending) might help.

**NOTE 3**: [This link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=queryPurchases) show others with the same issue.

Comment: Im having the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: No I didn't solved it yet :/

Comment: @Sealer_05, take a look at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143972327)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should find the soulution here !

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735936/implement-google-play-billing-library-version-2
```

I have tested this too with a closed alpha release to check if the subscription is active. When the subscription is not active anymore then the sku is not in the list of purchases anymore :

If i cancel the 5 minutes test-subscription then the sku is not anymore in the list. So this is working fine for me

Note skuname is the identifier i have passed before like "mytestsub.iap1.com" for example

my solution is :

```
private fun setupBillingClient() {
    mBillingClient = BillingClient
            .newBuilder(context!!)
            .enablePendingPurchases() // Useful for physical stores
            .setListener(this)
            .build()


    mBillingClient?.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {



                val purchasesResult = mBillingClient?.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) 




                // Init all the purchases to false in the shared preferences (security prevention)
                prefs.purchased = false


                // Retrieve and loop all the purchases done by the user
                // Update all the boolean related to the purchases done in the shared preferences
                if (purchasesResult?.purchasesList != null) {
                    for (purchase in purchasesResult.purchasesList!!) {


                        if (purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                            Log.e(Config.APPTAG, purchase.sku)
                            when (purchase.sku) {
                                skuname ->  {

                                    Log.e(Config.APPTAG, " Product "+purchase.sku+" is subscribed")



                                    // The subscription sku is found and active so then purchases to true in prefs
                                    prefs.purchased = true
                                }





                            }
                        }
                    }





                }
            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            // TODO Note: It's strongly recommended that you implement your own connection retry policy and override the onBillingServiceDisconnected() method. Make sure you maintain the BillingClient connection when executing any methods.


            Log.e(Config.APPTAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how to do this on billing library 5.0?

Comment: Hi take a look at my new answer here for library 5.0 to get all the active subscription skus

Answer (score 4):

The solution for Billing library 5.0 is a bit more different. But you should study the documentation to with the changes from library 4 to 5 .

To get all the "active" subscriptions to must do this:

The subscription SKU´s are now stored i the purchaseList Array !

Setting up the billing client :

```
private var skuList : MutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> = ArrayList()
private val subsProductsList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
private var productsDetailsList: MutableList<ProductDetails> = ArrayList()
  private var mBillingClient: BillingClient? = null




  // Add every sku to your list 
 subsProductsList.add(res.getString(R.string.product_id_subscribe_monthly)) 


setupBillingClient()





// Add all product-ids to the list (to get availabe products with prices later)

    for (i in 0 until  subsProductsList.size) {

        skuList.add(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId(subsProductsList[i])
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .build()
        )

    }



private fun setupBillingClient() {
    mBillingClient = BillingClient
            .newBuilder(context!!)
            .enablePendingPurchases() // Useful for physical stores
            .setListener(this)
            .build()


    mBillingClient?.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                



                queryPurchaseList()



            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            // TODO Note: It's strongly recommended that you implement your own connection retry policy and override the onBillingServiceDisconnected() method. Make sure you maintain the BillingClient connection when executing any methods.


            Log.e("Billing", "onBillingServiceDisconnected")
        }
    })
}



fun queryPurchaseList() {


    // new 2022 with version 5.0

    // Returns only active subscriptions
    mBillingClient?.queryPurchasesAsync(
        QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build()
    ) { billingResult, purchaseList ->
        // Process the result


        // Returns all active SUBS SKU´s !!
        checkPurchase(billingResult, purchaseList)
    }


}






fun checkPurchase(bresult:BillingResult, list:List<Purchase>?) {

    // Init all the purchases to false in the shared preferences (security prevention)
    prefs.SubscriptionPurchase = false


    // Retrieve and loop all the purchases done by the user
    // Update all the boolean related to the purchases done in the shared preferences
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {

        for (purchase in list) {


            if (purchase.isAcknowledged) {

                // getting the  single  product-id of every purchase in the list = sku
                val compareSKU = purchase.products.get(0)

                Log.e("Billing", "Compare SKU is $compareSKU")




                for (i in 0 until subsProductsList.size) {

                    if (subsProductsList[i].contains(compareSKU)) {
                        Log.e("Billing", " Product is subscribed and setting purchase to true ")

                        prefs.SubscriptionPurchase = true
                    }


                }


            }

      

            if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {

                // getting the product-id = sku
                val compareSKU = purchase.products.get(0)


             

                for (i in 0 until subsProductsList.size) {

                    Log.e("Billing", " Product purchasequery is purchased")





                    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {

                        Log.e("Billing", " Product purchasequery is purchased but not acknowledged")



                        val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                            .build()
                        mBillingClient!!.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, this)



                        // After purchase is acknowledeged you can set the purchase to true
                        prefs.SubscriptionPurchase = true



                    }




                }

                


            }







        }


       



    }


}
```

Comment: hi thanks for response , i use billingclient.querypurchaseasync to check if user purchased inapp product,, but is this solution will be viable for that??

Comment: i use java, and implemented billing and completed purchase flow and its working, but i am facing difficulties when verifying the purchase while user launches the app, i use billingclient.querypurchasesasync{} unfortunately always it returns error that billing service is disconnected , even though it passes the if statement billingclient.isconnected() .

Comment: Take a look at Github too here https://github.com/akshaaatt/Google-IAP ! This seems to be a good library to use too.

Comment: My function in kotlin works. (Kotlin is more convenient). As shown in the example first setup the billing client correctly witth .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS) and use queryPurchasesAsync. Then you are getting all "active" subscription SKU´s . I would make a separate billing class for all of this.

Comment: Hi also i would not start the billing check while launching the app. I put it in an activity that starts first like MainActivity for example.Then the code can execute without problem. During launching the app is maybe to fast !

Comment: Thank you so much, but my whole project is in Java, and i am asked not to use 3rd party library or extension. Hence i am stuck with google recommended solutions. How ever the library you recommended is really easy . Thanks again, more over i query purchase async on lunching the app to verify. but still no clue so trying to downgrade to library v4

Comment: you can convert java to kotlin (right mouseclick on file) and java works 100 % together with kotlin. In my example you see the solution. Every purchase is loaded and in the loop is checked if if any of the active SKU´s is equal with one of your SKU´s in your subsproducts list. Then if purchases is acknowledged set purchase to true. This is working without any problems : Look here too https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5. !! There are the java function for querypurchasesasync too.

Comment: look at my new answer . i have made an java example for you in a test class

Answer (score 1):

JAVA example with Test class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams;
import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;

import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener;

 import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult;

import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase;
import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener;
import com.android.billingclient.api.QueryPurchasesParams;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {

   private Context mContext;
   BillingClient billingClient;
   private ArrayList<String> subsProductsList;




   public Test(Context context) {
  super();
  this.mContext = context;
  subsProductsList = new ArrayList<>();





  subsProductsList.add("my-subs-sku");



  initBilling();
   }



   public void initBilling() {

  billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext)

          .enablePendingPurchases()
          .build();



  billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
     @Override
     public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
           // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.


           queryPurchaseList();
        }
     }
     @Override
     public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
     }
  });



   }


   public void queryPurchaseList() {

  // Get all "active" subscription SKU´s now

  billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
          QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS).build(),
          new PurchasesResponseListener() {
             public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(
                     BillingResult billingResult,
                     List<Purchase> purchases) {
                // Process the result


                for (Purchase purch : purchases)  {


                   // First check if the purchase is already acknowledged !! Then we continue here !
                   if (purch.isAcknowledged()) {

                      // getting the single SKU of each purchase - is stored in get(0)
                   String  checkSKU = purch.getProducts().get(0);



                   // now we are checking if the sku stored in getproducts().get(0) is equal the sku from your list of sku´s
                      for (int i = 0; i < subsProductsList.size(); ++i) {
                         if (subsProductsList.get(i).contains(checkSKU)) {
                            Log.e("Billing", " Product is subscribed and setting purchase to true ");

                            // Set here your purchase to true in prefs !!

                         }

                      }


                   }



                   // Here we are checking if the purchase is purchased but not acknowledged ..then we must acknowledge first

                   if (purch.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {


                      for (int i = 0; i < subsProductsList.size(); ++i) {

                         if (!purch.isAcknowledged()) {


                               AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                                       AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                               .setPurchaseToken(purch.getPurchaseToken())
                                               .build();
                               billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

                                     if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                                        Log.e("Billing", "Purchase was successful");

                                     }
                                  }
                               });


                               // Set here your purchase to true in prefs !!


                         }




                      }


                   }







                }



             }
          }
  );



}
 @Override
   public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working for me now. Really struggled with this problem for weeks. Hats of to you!.

Comment: No problem ! This is a community here and i have learned here so many things so its  good to give something back and help other people. And the billing library it not very easy to understand ...Greets Frank

Comment: hi,  if the in app item is purchased we get purchase token and if item is not purchased the  list is empty what if the item is purchased and refunded?? i do some times get the old purchase token! how do we get purchase state not purchased or refunded is there a way ?

Comment: Hi ! Refunded purchases or canceled purchases will disappear instantly from the requested sku list. You will get only "active" subscriptions. Purchased and refunded = not purchases in my opinion so the sku will be not in the list. Maybe only for 1 - 2 minutes. Only if a user is canceling his subsription ( for example 1 year) then the sku will still remain in the list with status purchases and acknowledged until the subscription is ending.  I had never any problems with this. Make a test purchases and then refund the test purchase. The sku dissapears from the list within 1 - 5 minutes .

Comment: yes , thanks again, is it advisable to query purchase async when my app starts? or will it create any issues with google??

Comment: I initiate the my class in Mainactivity for example. Then OnResume() i call something like this :   billingHelper.querypurchases() . Then if any purchase is = true  i save it to my preferenes  (ispurchase = true).